# Cannot Change theme in Drupal 7.24, ACCESS DENIED

Tags: theming

I just did a clean install of Drupal 7.24
Everything seems ok so far, but as soon as I try to change the theme it says ACCESS DENIED. You ARE NOT AUTHORISED TO ACCESS THIS PAGE!!!!
Very strange!!! I was working with same OS and same configuration before, not sure whats happening now....
Can anyone help please?
I have googled and tried every possible solution, but seems not working any of them,I emptied the cache of browser, repaired the session table and cleared cache from drupal settings, but no avail....

Comment: Are you logged in as an admin and have you checked the permissions? Under **System**, there's a permission for "Administer themes".